# Plot each Dask partition seperatly using python

Tags: python, dask

I'm using `Dask` to read 500 parquet files and it does it much faster than other methods that I have tested.

Each parquet file contains a time column and many other variable columns.

My goal is to create a single plot that will have 500 lines of variable vs time.

When I use the following code, it works very fast compared to all other methods that I have tested but it gives me a single "line" on the plot:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

start = time.time()

ddf = dd.read_parquet("results_parq/*.parquet")
plt.plot(ddf['t'].compute(),ddf['reg'].compute())
plt.show()
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

[image]

from my understanding, it happens because Dask just plots the following:

```
t
0
0.01
.
.
100
0
0.01
.
.
100
0
```

What I mean it plots a huge column instead of 500 columns.

One possible solution that I tried to do is to plot it in a for loop over the partitions:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

start = time.time()

ddf = dd.read_parquet("results_parq/*.parquet")
for p in ddf.partitions:
    plt.plot(p['t'].compute(),p['reg'].compute())
plt.show()
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

It does the job and the resulting plot looks like I want:

[image]

However, it results in much longer times.

Is there a way to do something like this but yet to use Dask multicore benefits? Like somehow use map_partitions for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

as a start, you cannot normally make matplotlib draw to the same figure from multiple processes, as the renderers aren't using shared memory. (neither should they from a programming point of view)

drawing 500 lines is a very simple task for matplotlib and the problem maybe not in matplotlib.

your dask workers are likely sending data sequentially to your main process, hence the slowdown. (each worker has to wait for master to request data then send it then wait for confirmation, then wait for next order to come, etc)

you can force them to send their data faster by prefetching all the data before you start plotting by matplotlib.

```py
import numpy as np

ddf = dd.read_parquet("results_parq/*.parquet")

# compute length of each partition
lengths = ddf.map_partitions(len).compute()
# get all partitions at once
ddf2 = ddf.compute()

# calculate each parition start and end
lengths = list(lengths)
lengths.insert(0,0)
accumelated_lengths= np.cumsum(lengths)

# plot each partition
for i in range(len(accumelated_lengths)-1):
    plt.plot(ddf2['t'][accumelated_lengths[i]:accumelated_lengths[i+1]],
             ddf2['reg'][accumelated_lengths[i]:accumelated_lengths[i+1]])
plt.show()
```

Edit: making 500 calls to `plt.plot` is probably slowing you down too, you could use [matplotlib.LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) instead, it takes 1/20 of the time for 500 lines.

```py
# plot each partition
lines = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(accumelated_lengths) - 1):
    lines.append(tuple(zip(ddf2['a'][accumelated_lengths[i]:accumelated_lengths[i + 1]],
                          ddf2['b'][accumelated_lengths[i]:accumelated_lengths[i + 1]])))
coll = LineCollection(lines,colors = np.random.random([len(lines),3]))
ax.add_collection(coll)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The plot indeed works fine. Doing the compute() before the loop gives an error saying DataFrame has no attribute 'partitions' tho. Because it combines all the partitions into a single huge DataFrame from what I understand.

Comment: @Ben i have fixed the above code to calculate each parition size, but if it's known or fixed then the code could be simplified greatly, and will be faster ... having to calculate the length of each partition is slow and takes some code, but this is probably much faster than your original implementation.

Comment: It works faster than the original post, Thank you. However, I'm looking for some built-in Dask method/multicore solution. Because reading the parquet files takes 0.1 seconds from what I timed and doing that for loop plotting makes it slow (and anyway I don't care in what order it will draw the lines, so it can be parallel).

Comment: @Ben dask isn't going to help you as drawing is a single threaded thing, you just need to optimize the rendered, i added a LineCollection which should be a lot faster for large number of lines, (it takes 0.18 seconds to make the rendered, but opening the display window depends on your backend).